# Asynchronous code with dependency inversion and generics

Tags: asynchronous, struct, rust, rust-tokio

I'm trying to create a minimal clean architecture structure with Rust. Basically a controller that receives a request, a use case that handles the logic, an entitiy that holds the data model, and a repository that actually retrieves the data. Here is a diagram of the structure I'm using: [diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOZy5.jpg).

A synchronous version of this can be see at [Generics and dependency inversion with multiple structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70004446/generics-and-dependency-inversion-with-multiple-structs;) now I'm trying to do it asynchronously with Tokio: https://crates.io/crates/tokio. For starters I wont set the repository, so will pull the data directly from the use case.

Here is a playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ed9c8c0e12c043ad4e3e4bea956fa0cc

Here same code for reference:

```rust
#![allow(dead_code)]

use async_trait::async_trait;
use std::io::Error;
use tokio::time;

// CUSTOM RETURN TYPE - - - - - - - - - - -
type AsyncResult<T> = Result<T, Error>;

// ENTITY - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
#[derive(Debug)]
struct User {
  pub id: i32,
  pub name: String,
}

// USE CASE - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
#[async_trait]
trait IUserGetAllUseCase {
  fn new() -> UserGetAllUseCase;
  async fn execute(&self) -> AsyncResult<Vec<User>>;
}

struct UserGetAllUseCase;

#[async_trait]
impl IUserGetAllUseCase for UserGetAllUseCase {
  fn new() -> UserGetAllUseCase {
    UserGetAllUseCase {}
  }

  async fn execute(&self) -> AsyncResult<Vec<User>> {
    // Simulating async data retrieval from persistence
    time::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(3)).await;
    let user_1 = User {
      id: 1,
      name: String::from("user_1"),
    };
    let user_2 = User {
      id: 2,
      name: String::from("user_2"),
    };
    let users = vec![user_1, user_2];

    Ok(users)
  }
}

// CONTROLLER - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
struct UserGetAllController<T> {
  user_get_all_use_case: T,
}

impl<T: IUserGetAllUseCase> UserGetAllController<T> {
  fn new(user_get_all_use_case: T) -> UserGetAllController<T> {
    UserGetAllController {
      user_get_all_use_case,
    }
  }

  async fn execute(&self) -> AsyncResult<Vec<User>> {
    let users = self.user_get_all_use_case.execute().await;

    users
  }
}

// MOCK SERVER - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> AsyncResult<()> {
  let user_get_all_use_case = UserGetAllUseCase::new();
  let user_get_all_controller = UserGetAllController::new(user_get_all_use_case);
  let users = user_get_all_controller.execute().await?;

  println!("{:#?}", users);

  Ok(())
}
```

Ok, this works, is asynchronous.
Now I want to add a repository trait to be able to create any repositories I may need to retrieve data from different persistence systems: PostgreSQL, filesystem, etc.
To do this I create `IUserRepository`, and the implement in in `PostgreSQLUserRepository`.

Here is a playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8758491ba16eee3821df8d1f800c9c85.
And here the same code for reference:

```rust
#![allow(dead_code)]

use async_trait::async_trait;
use std::io::Error;
use tokio::time;

// CUSTOM RETURN TYPE - - - - - - - - - - -
type AsyncResult<T> = Result<T, Error>;

// ENTITY - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct User {
  pub id: i32,
  pub name: String,
}

// REPOSITORY - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
#[async_trait]
pub trait IUserRepository {
  async fn company_get_all(&self) -> AsyncResult<Vec<User>>;
}

pub struct UserRepository;

#[async_trait]
impl IUserRepository for UserRepository {
  async fn company_get_all(&self) -> AsyncResult<Vec<User>> {
    // Simulating async data retrieval from persistence
    time::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(3)).await;
    let user_1 = User {
      id: 1,
      name: String::from("user_1"),
    };
    let user_2 = User {
      id: 2,
      name: String::from("user_2"),
    };
    let users = vec![user_1, user_2];

    Ok(users)
  }
}

// USE CASE - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
#[async_trait]
trait IUserGetAllUseCase {
  fn new<T: IUserRepository>(user_repository: T) -> UserGetAllUseCase<T>;
  async fn execute(&self) -> AsyncResult<Vec<User>>;
}

struct UserGetAllUseCase<T> {
  user_repository: T,
}

#[async_trait]
impl<T: IUserRepository> IUserGetAllUseCase for UserGetAllUseCase<T> {
  fn new<K: IUserRepository>(user_repository: K) -> UserGetAllUseCase<K> {
    UserGetAllUseCase { user_repository }
  }

  async fn execute(&self) -> AsyncResult<Vec<User>> {
    let users = self.user_repository.company_get_all().await;

    users
    // Two errors here:
    // «future cannot be sent between threads safely»
    // «future created by async block is not `Send`»
  }
}

// CONTROLLER - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
struct UserGetAllController<T> {
  user_get_all_use_case: T,
}

impl<T: IUserGetAllUseCase> UserGetAllController<T> {
  fn new(user_get_all_use_case: T) -> UserGetAllController<T> {
    UserGetAllController {
      user_get_all_use_case,
    }
  }

  async fn execute(&self) -> AsyncResult<Vec<User>> {
    let users = self.user_get_all_use_case.execute().await;

    users
  }
}

// MOCK SERVER - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> AsyncResult<()> {
  let user_repository = UserRepository {};
  let user_get_all_use_case = UserGetAllUseCase::<UserRepository>::new(user_repository);
  let user_get_all_controller = UserGetAllController::new(user_get_all_use_case);
  let users = user_get_all_controller.execute().await?;

  println!("{:#?}", users);

  Ok(())
}
```

As you see, I get two errors:

```
«future cannot be sent between threads safely»
«future created by async block is not `Send`»
```

I'm not sure why this wont compile while my previous structure was similar, and it was compiled and run without issues.

Any help will be welcome ))

Answer (score 1):

`async fn`s create "state machines", which you can think of as similar to an `enum` with each variant representing the data required between every `await` point.

These state machines still need to obey Rust's concurrency guarantees, however, and critically, any data shared across await points must be `Send`, since it might be executed on a different thread by your executor.

If you run the playground link, you get the following errors:

```
  --> src/main.rs:61:53
   |
61 |     async fn execute(&self) -> AsyncResult<Vec<User>> {
   |  _____________________________________________________^
62 | |     let users = self.user_repository.company_get_all().await;
63 | |
64 | |     users
...  |
67 | |     // «future created by async block is not `Send`»
68 | |   }
   | |___^ future created by async block is not `Send`
   |
note: captured value is not `Send` because `&` references cannot be sent unless their referent is `Sync`
  --> src/main.rs:61:21
   |
61 |   async fn execute(&self) -> AsyncResult<Vec<User>> {
   |                     ^^^^ has type `&UserGetAllUseCase<T>` which is not `Send`, because `UserGetAllUseCase<T>` is not `Sync`
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn Future<Output = Result<Vec<User>, std::io::Error>> + Send`
help: consider further restricting this bound
   |
56 | impl<T: IUserRepository + std::marker::Sync> IUserGetAllUseCase for UserGetAllUseCase<T> {
   |                         +++++++++++++++++++

error: future cannot be sent between threads safely
```

There's a little bit to unpack here, but the main point is on this line:

```
&self has type `&UserGetAllUseCase<T>` which is not `Send`, because `UserGetAllUseCase<T>` is not `Sync`
```

The solution is to mark your `IUserRepository` as `Send + Sync` (there's another issue that the compiler will raise which is similar but also requires the `Send` bound).

This is made slightly more confusing by trait objects. Generally, you don't have to worry too much about `Send` and `Sync`, because they are "auto traits", meaning they are automatically derived where possible by the compiler.

However, when you create a trait object, you erase all knowledge of the "real" type of the data other than what is specified in the trait bound.

For example, a `Box<dyn Foo>` isn't known to be `Send` even if it actually contains a `()`. You have to tell the compiler that the `Send` bound is important explicitly.

Some more reading on futures, specifically w.r.t. send-ness: https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/07_workarounds/03_send_approximation.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't know neither about `Send` nor `Sync`. In the docs you sent I read: «Some async fn state machines are safe to be sent across threads, while others are not». Is this issue related to the fact that I'm using Tokio runtime? Would I avoid having to add `+ Send + Sync` by using a different runtime?

Comment: Rust is different to many other languages in that the "executor/event loop" and "futures" are quite separated. Futures and async functions are part of the language, and are independent of the runtime, so no, using a different runtime wouldn't change this. Instead, it's probably worth accepting that you want the `Send + Sync` bounds on things. If you want, you can define a "combination trait" of sorts (to save some keystrokes), as in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26983355/is-there-a-way-to-combine-multiple-traits-in-order-to-define-a-new-trait

Comment: Futures and async functions by themselves don't require to be `Send` or `Sync`. `async-trait` desugars to `Pin<Box<dyn Future + Send + 'async_trait>>`, you could define your own trait returning non-send futures instead and as long as you run them on an executor that doesn't require `Send` futures, you'll be fine. If you want any kind of concurrency from the tokio runtime, you'll need them to be `Send`, as defined by the bounds on `task::spawn`.

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a38e6d5da0b8f6d3e40975814e8cfe28